# Evaluate using Mathematica or otherwise the value of $f'(0)$

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions

If we have$$f(a)=_3F_2\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{a+1}{2},\frac{a+2}{2};
   \frac{a+3}{2},\frac{a+3}{2};1\right)$$
where $a\geq 0$ and $_3F_2$ is the Hypergeometric function with unit argument.

> Evaluate using Mathematica or otherwise the value of
> $f'(0)$ (the first derivative of $f(a)$ at $0$).

I am requesting a code with answer if possible in Wolfram Mathematica.

Sorry, I am new to Wolfram Mathematica.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From definition of `HypergeometricPFQ` as Series representations we have:

$\underset{a\to 0}{\text{lim}}\frac{\partial }{\partial a}\, _3F_2\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}+\frac{a}{2},1+\frac{a}{2};\frac{3}{2}+\frac{a}{2},\frac{3}{2}+\frac{a}{2};1\right)=\\\underset{a\to 0}{\text{lim}}\frac{\partial
   }{\partial a}\left(\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \frac{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)_k \left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{a}{2}\right)_k \left(1+\frac{a}{2}\right)_k}{k! \left(\left(\frac{3}{2}+\frac{a}{2}\right)_k\right){}^2}\right)=\\\sum
   _{k=0}^{\infty } \left(\underset{a\to 0}{\text{lim}}\frac{\partial }{\partial a}\frac{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)_k \left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{a}{2}\right)_k \left(1+\frac{a}{2}\right)_k}{k!
   \left(\left(\frac{3}{2}+\frac{a}{2}\right)_k\right){}^2}\right)=\\\sum _{k=0}^{\infty }
   \left(\underset{a\to 0}{\text{lim}}\frac{\partial }{\partial a}\frac{(1+a) \Gamma \left(\frac{3}{2}+\frac{a}{2}\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{2}+k\right) \Gamma \left(1+\frac{a}{2}+k\right)}{(1+a+2 k) \sqrt{\pi } \Gamma
   \left(1+\frac{a}{2}\right) \Gamma (1+k) \Gamma \left(\frac{3}{2}+\frac{a}{2}+k\right)}\right)=\\\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \left(\underset{a\to 0}{\text{lim}}\left(-\frac{(1+a) \Gamma \left(\frac{3}{2}+\frac{a}{2}\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{2}+k\right) \Gamma \left(1+\frac{a}{2}+k\right)}{(1+a+2 k)^2 \sqrt{\pi } \Gamma
   \left(1+\frac{a}{2}\right) \Gamma (1+k) \Gamma \left(\frac{3}{2}+\frac{a}{2}+k\right)}+\frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{3}{2}+\frac{a}{2}\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{2}+k\right) \Gamma \left(1+\frac{a}{2}+k\right)}{(1+a+2 k)
   \sqrt{\pi } \Gamma \left(1+\frac{a}{2}\right) \Gamma (1+k) \Gamma \left(\frac{3}{2}+\frac{a}{2}+k\right)}-\frac{(1+a) \Gamma \left(\frac{3}{2}+\frac{a}{2}\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{2}+k\right) \Gamma
   \left(1+\frac{a}{2}+k\right) \psi ^{(0)}\left(1+\frac{a}{2}\right)}{2 (1+a+2 k) \sqrt{\pi } \Gamma \left(1+\frac{a}{2}\right) \Gamma (1+k) \Gamma \left(\frac{3}{2}+\frac{a}{2}+k\right)}+\frac{(1+a) \Gamma
   \left(\frac{3}{2}+\frac{a}{2}\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{2}+k\right) \Gamma \left(1+\frac{a}{2}+k\right) \psi ^{(0)}\left(\frac{3}{2}+\frac{a}{2}\right)}{2 (1+a+2 k) \sqrt{\pi } \Gamma \left(1+\frac{a}{2}\right) \Gamma (1+k)
   \Gamma \left(\frac{3}{2}+\frac{a}{2}+k\right)}+\frac{(1+a) \Gamma \left(\frac{3}{2}+\frac{a}{2}\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{2}+k\right) \Gamma \left(1+\frac{a}{2}+k\right) \psi ^{(0)}\left(1+\frac{a}{2}+k\right)}{2 (1+a+2 k)
   \sqrt{\pi } \Gamma \left(1+\frac{a}{2}\right) \Gamma (1+k) \Gamma \left(\frac{3}{2}+\frac{a}{2}+k\right)}-\frac{(1+a) \Gamma \left(\frac{3}{2}+\frac{a}{2}\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{2}+k\right) \Gamma
   \left(1+\frac{a}{2}+k\right) \psi ^{(0)}\left(\frac{3}{2}+\frac{a}{2}+k\right)}{2 (1+a+2 k) \sqrt{\pi } \Gamma \left(1+\frac{a}{2}\right) \Gamma (1+k) \Gamma \left(\frac{3}{2}+\frac{a}{2}+k\right)}\right)\right)=\\\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \left(-\frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{2}+k\right)}{2 (1+2 k)^2 \Gamma \left(\frac{3}{2}+k\right)}+\frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{2}+k\right)}{2 (1+2 k) \Gamma \left(\frac{3}{2}+k\right)}+\frac{\gamma  \Gamma
   \left(\frac{1}{2}+k\right)}{4 (1+2 k) \Gamma \left(\frac{3}{2}+k\right)}+\frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{2}+k\right) \psi ^{(0)}\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)}{4 (1+2 k) \Gamma \left(\frac{3}{2}+k\right)}+\frac{\Gamma
   \left(\frac{1}{2}+k\right) \psi ^{(0)}(1+k)}{4 (1+2 k) \Gamma \left(\frac{3}{2}+k\right)}-\frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{2}+k\right) \psi ^{(0)}\left(\frac{3}{2}+k\right)}{4 (1+2 k) \Gamma \left(\frac{3}{2}+k\right)}\right)=\\\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } -\frac{-2+(-1-2 k) H_k+(1+2 k) H_{\frac{1}{2}+k}+2 k (-4+\ln (4))+\ln (4)}{2 (1+2 k)^3}=\\\int_0^1 \left(\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } -\frac{-2+\frac{(-1-2 k) \left(1-t^k\right)}{1-t}+\frac{(1+2 k) \left(1-t^{\frac{1}{2}+k}\right)}{1-t}+2 k (-4+\ln (4))+\ln (4)}{2 (1+2 k)^3}\right) \, dt=\int_0^1 \frac{1}{16}
   \left(-\frac{2 \Phi \left(t,2,\frac{1}{2}\right)}{1+\sqrt{t}}-\pi ^2 (-4+\ln (4))-14 \zeta (3)\right) \, dt=\\\frac{\pi ^2}{4}-\frac{1}{16} \pi ^2 \ln (4)-\frac{7 \zeta (3)}{8}-\int_0^1 \frac{\Phi
   \left(t,2,\frac{1}{2}\right)}{8 \left(1+\sqrt{t}\right)} \, dt=\\\frac{\pi ^2}{4}-\frac{1}{16} \pi ^2 \ln (4)-\frac{7 \zeta (3)}{8}-\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \int_0^1 \frac{t^k}{\left(\frac{1}{2}+k\right)^2 \left(8
   \left(1+\sqrt{t}\right)\right)} \, dt=\\\frac{\pi ^2}{4}-\frac{1}{16} \pi ^2 \ln (4)-\frac{7 \zeta (3)}{8}-\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \frac{-H_k+H_{\frac{1}{2}+k}}{2 (1+2 k)^2}=\\\frac{\pi ^2}{4}-\frac{1}{4} \pi ^2 \ln (2)-\frac{1}{2} \sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \frac{H_{\frac{1}{2}+k}}{(1+2 k)^2}=\\\frac{\pi ^2}{4}-\frac{1}{4} \pi ^2 \ln (2)-\frac{1}{2} \sum _{j=1}^{\infty } \left(\sum _{k=0}^{\infty }
   \frac{\frac{1}{2}+k}{\left(j \left(\frac{1}{2}+j+k\right)\right) (1+2 k)^2}\right)=\\\frac{\pi ^2}{4}-\frac{1}{4} \pi ^2 \ln (2)-\frac{1}{2} \sum _{j=1}^{\infty } \left(\frac{\gamma }{4 j^2}+\frac{\ln (4)}{4 j^2}+\frac{\psi
   ^{(0)}\left(\frac{1}{2}+j\right)}{4 j^2}\right)=\\\frac{\pi ^2}{4}-\frac{1}{4} \pi ^2 \ln (2)-\frac{1}{48} \pi ^2 (\gamma +\ln (4))-\sum _{j=1}^{\infty } \frac{\psi ^{(0)}\left(\frac{1}{2}+j\right)}{4 j^2}=\\\frac{\pi
   ^2}{4}-\frac{1}{4} \pi ^2 \ln (2)-\frac{1}{48} \pi ^2 (\gamma +\ln (4))-\int_0^{\infty } \left(\sum _{j=1}^{\infty } \frac{\frac{e^{-t}}{t}-\frac{(1+t)^{-\frac{1}{2}-j}}{t}}{4 j^2}\right) \, dt=\\\frac{\pi ^2}{4}-\frac{1}{4}
   \pi ^2 \ln (2)-\frac{1}{48} \pi ^2 (\gamma +\ln (4))-\int_0^{\infty } \left(\frac{e^{-t} \pi ^2}{24 t}-\frac{\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{1}{1+t}\right)}{4 t \sqrt{1+t}}\right) \, dt=\\\frac{\pi ^2}{4}-\frac{1}{4} \pi ^2 \ln
   (2)-\frac{7 \zeta (3)}{16}$

**Using definitions:**

$H_x=\int_0^1 \frac{1-t^x}{1-t} \, dt$

$\Phi \left(t,2,\frac{1}{2}\right)=\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \frac{t^k}{\left(\frac{1}{2}+k\right)^2}$

$H_k=\sum _{j=1}^{\infty } \frac{k}{j (j+k)}$

$\psi ^{(0)}\left(\frac{1}{2}+j\right)=\int_0^{\infty } \left(\frac{e^{-t}}{t}-\frac{(1+t)^{-\frac{1}{2}-j}}{t}\right) \, dt$

---

$$\underset{a\to 0}{\text{lim}}\frac{\partial }{\partial a}\, _3F_2\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{a+1}{2},\frac{a+2}{2};\frac{a+3}{2},\frac{a+3}{2};1\right)=\color{red}{-\frac{7 \zeta (3)}{16}+\frac{\pi ^2}{4}-\frac{1}{4} \pi ^2 \ln (2)}$$

```
HoldForm[Limit[D[HypergeometricPFQ[{1/2, (a + 1)/2, (a + 2)/2}, {(a + 3)/2, (a + 3)/2}, 1], a], a -> 0] ==
\[Pi]^2/4 - 1/16 \[Pi]^2 Log[4] - (7 Zeta[3])/8 - 
Integrate[LerchPhi[t, 2, 1/2]/(8 (1 + Sqrt[t])), {t, 0, 1}] == \[Pi]^2/4 - 1/4 \[Pi]^2 Log[2] - 
1/2*Sum[HarmonicNumber[1/2 + k]/(1 + 2 k)^2, {k, 0, 
  Infinity}] == \[Pi]^2/4 - 1/4 \[Pi]^2 Log[2] - (7 Zeta[3])/16]
```

We can check:

```
 SOL1 = N[\[Pi]^2/4 - 1/4 \[Pi]^2 Log[2] - (7 Zeta[3])/16, 50]
 (* 0.23122908917573801863436751581925439504379858686425 *)
 Needs["NumericalCalculus`"];
 SOL2 = ND[f[a], a, 0, WorkingPrecision -> 50, Method -> NIntegrate]
 (* 0.23122908917573801863436751581925439504379858686430 - 2.*10^-50 I *)
 SOL1 - SOL2

 (*-5.*10^-50 + 2.*10^-50 I *)
```

Comment: While exact calculation is what we are expecting, it would be recommended to explain several steps above, e.g. after the 4-th equal sign how do you get rid of $\lim_{a \to 0} \frac{\partial}{\partial a}\dots$ with several functions involving $a$ as an argument and obtain harmonic functions or in the next step how does integral appear $\int_{0}^{1}\dots$.

Comment: Thanks for the beautiful effort. Please explain how did you take limit and differentiation inside the sum (which needs some condition to be allowed). Also please explain how fid you get the sums and integrals and the steps involved in between. Thank you for your effort

Comment: @Max I'm not going to prove anything to you under what conditions these equations are met, because this forum is about the Mathematica program, not the math itself. Second, I'm not a mathematician, I'm an engineer, so proving isn't my strong suit.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the edit.

Comment: @Max I'll try to provide a bit more mathematical justification of the above reasoning when I find a bit of spare time, I hope until tomorow evening.

Comment: @Artes Thank you so much. I will wait for your answer. Thanks a ton.

Comment: @Artes It is a gentle reminder for your answer. Thank you.

Comment: Max, I have examined derivation of the result with *Mathematica* better organizing calculation, noetheless in substantial part I've walked along the same path as @MariuszIwaniuk has done and upvoted his answer.  So far I haven't found much simpler approach, nevertheless I will try to improve derivation in the next two days. This approach is correct however there are chances that we can find a simpler way. If you have any questions, ask me in order to explain calculation in a better way.

Answer (score 6):

Let's define

```
f[a_] := HypergeometricPFQ[{1/2, (a + 1)/2, (a + 2)/2}, {(a + 3)/2, (a + 3)/2}, 1]

HypergeometricPFQ[{1/2, (a + 1)/2, (a + 2)/2}, {(a + 3)/2, (a + 3)/2}, 1]//
TraditionalForm
```

[image]

> ```
> HypergeometricPFQ[{a1,..., ap},{ b1,...,bq},z] is the generalized
> hypergeometric function pFq(a;b;z).
> ```

If we evaluate simply

```
Derivative[1][f][0] // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

we get a symbolic representation by introducing another special functions (derivatives of $_3 F_2$ with respect to its parameters $a_i$ and $b_j$) which can't be expanded into other well (better) known functions. Moreover the system seems to choke on numerical evaluation.

```
Table[ f[a], {a, Range[-2, 2]}]
```

> ```
>  {1, 1, Pi^2/8, (4 (-2 + Pi))/Pi, 9/32 (-4 + Pi^2)}
> ```

Now we can **estimate symbolically** derivative of $f'(0)$ simply taking $\frac{f(1)-f(0)}{1}$ or $\frac{f(1)-f(-1)}{2}$

```
{(f[1] - f[0])/1, (f[1] - f[-1])/2} // Simplify
N @ %
```

> ```
> { 4 - 8/Pi - Pi^2/8, 3/2 - 4/Pi}
> { 0.21982, 0.22676}
> ```

Comparing with the plot this appears to be a good approximation. Moreover evaluation at close points yields a similar, even more precise result (up to $10^{-5}$) without using external packages

```
(f'[0.00001] + f'[-0.00001])/2
```

> ```
>  0.231229
> ```

```
Plot[{f[a], (4 - 8/Pi - Pi^2/8) a + Pi^2/8}, {a, -5, 4}, 
  AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotRange -> {0, 6.5}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Thick, Dashed}, PlotLegends -> Placed["Expressions", {0.8, 0.75}], 
  Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[{0, Pi^2/8}]}]
```

[image: enter code here]

**Derivation of the exact result within Mathematica**

Partial sums of geometric series can be calculated simply with

```
ForAll[ n, n ∈ Integers && n >= 2, 
       (1 - q^n)/(1 - q) == Sum[q^k, {k, 0, n - 1}]] // Resolve
```

> ```
> True
> ```

This also  yields with $n \to \infty$ the sum of geometric series as well as the starting point to the definition of the hypergeometric series and by the analytic continuation the hypergeometric function:

```
Sum[ Gamma[k + a] Gamma[k + b] Gamma[c]/(
       Gamma[a] Gamma[b] Gamma[k + c] k!) q^k, { k, 0,3}]
```

> ```
> Hypergeometric2F1[a, b, c, q]
> ```

The above formula yields for $a=b=c=1$ the sum of geometric series, more precisely  this should be a conditional expression. Analogously we can define $_3 F_2$ function.

The following yields a basic definition of the Euler gamma function

```
Integrate[ t^(x - 1) Exp[-t], {t, 0,  ∞}, Assumptions -> Re[x] > 0]
```

> ```
> Gamma[x]
> ```

which by the analytic continuation provides a meromorphic function in the whole complex plane

```
{FunctionMeromorphic[#, x], FunctionDomain[#, x, Complexes]}&@Gamma[x]
```

> ```
> {True, Re[x] > 0 || x \[NotElement] Integers}
> ```

We use also

```
FullSimplify[ Gamma[a1 + k]/Gamma[a1] == Pochhammer[a1, k]]
```

> ```
>  True
> ```

Denoting by $d_0 = f'(0)$ we can write from the definition that wherever the series is absolutely convergent:

$$d_0=\lim_{a\to 0}\frac{d}{d a}\, _3F_2\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{a+1}{2},\frac{a}{2}+1;\frac{a+3}{2},\frac{a+3}{2};1\right)=\sum _{k=0}^{\infty }\left(\underset{a\to 0}{\lim}\frac{d
}{d a} \frac{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)_k \left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{a}{2}\right)_k \left(1+\frac{a}{2}\right)_k}{k! \left(\left(\frac{3}{2}+\frac{a}{2}\right)_k\right){}^2}\right)$$

which is the case here, e.g.

```
SumConvergence[ (Pochhammer[1/2, k] Pochhammer[(a + 1)/2, k]
                 Pochhammer[(a + 2)/2, k]/(Pochhammer[(a + 3)/2, k]^2 k!), k]
```

> ```
>  True
> ```

The same holds also including the oprerator $\underset{a\to 0}{\lim}\frac{d}{d a}$ under the sum sign. Then differentiating with respect to $a$ we obtain

```
Assuming[k ∈ PositiveIntegers, 
  Limit[ D[ FunctionExpand[(
    Pochhammer[1/2, k] Pochhammer[(a + 1)/2, k] Pochhammer[(a + 2)/2, k])/(
    Pochhammer[(a + 3)/2, k]^2 k!)], a], a -> 0] // FullSimplify]
```

> ```
> -((-2 + (-1 - 2 k) HarmonicNumber[k] + (1 + 2k) HarmonicNumber[1/2 + k]
>     + 2 k (-4 + Log[4]) + Log[4])/(2 (1 + 2 k)^3))
> ```

The above limit yields $0$ for $k=0$. The only problematic term when summing from $k=1$ to $k=\infty$ is `-HarmonicNumber[1/2 + k]/(2(1 + 2k)^2)`

```
d0 = Sum[-((-2 + (-1 - 2 k) HarmonicNumber[k] + 2 k (-4 + Log[4])
         + Log[4])/(2 (1 + 2 k)^3)), {k, ∞}] 
   - Sum[ HarmonicNumber[1/2 + k]/(2 (1 + 2 k)^2), {k, ∞}]
```

> ```
>  -1/8 ((-4 + Pi^2) (-2 + Log[4])) 
>   - Sum[ HarmonicNumber[1/2 + k]/(2(1 + 2k)^2), {k, ∞}]
> ```

We denote:

```
 d01 = -1/8 ((-4 + Pi^2) (-2 + Log[4]));
 d02 = - Sum[ HarmonicNumber[1/2 + k]/(2(1 + 2k)^2), {k, ∞}];
```

Using the following identity

```
Sum[-((k + 1/2)/(2 m (2 k + 1)^2 (m + k + 1/2))), {m, ∞}]// FullSimplify
```

> ```
> -HarmonicNumber[1/2 + k]/(2 (1 + 2 k)^2)
> ```

we can recast the hard term by summing it first with respect to $k$

```
Sum[-((k + 1/2)/(2 m (2 k + 1)^2 (m + k + 1/2))), {k, ∞}]//FunctionExpand
```

> ```
> -((-2 + EulerGamma + Log[4] + PolyGamma[0, 3/2 + m])/(8 m^2))
> ```

Next we exploit two identities

```
-PolyGamma[0, 3/2 + m]/(8 m^2) == -(1/(
   8 m^2)) (PolyGamma[0, 1/2 + m] + 1/(1/2 + m)) // FullSimplify
```

> ```
>  True
> ```

and

```
Integrate[ Exp[-t]/t - 1/((t + 1)^(m + 1/2) t), {t, 0, ∞},
  Assumptions -> m > 0]
```

> ```
> PolyGamma[0, 1/2 + m]
> ```

Summing up

```
d02 = 1 - Log[2] - 1/48 Pi^2 (EulerGamma + Log[4]) + 
      Integrate[-Sum[ Exp[-t]/(8 m^2 t) - 1/(8 m^2 (t + 1)^(m + 1/2) t), 
                     {m, ∞}], {t, 0, ∞}] // FullSimplify
```

> ```
> 1 - Log[2] - (7 Zeta[3])/16
> ```

In mathematical notation we have
$$ d_{02}= -\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_{k+\frac{1}{2}}}{2(2k+1)^2}=-\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{\gamma-2+\ln(4)+\psi^{(0)}(\frac{3}{2}+m)}{8m^2}$$
and
$$-\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{\psi^{(0)}(\frac{3}{2}+m)}{8m^2}=-\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{4m^2(2m+1)}-\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{\psi^{(0)}(\frac{1}{2}+m)}{8m^2}=\\=1-\ln(2)-\frac{\pi^2}{48}(\gamma+\ln(4))-\int_{0}^{\infty}\left( \sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{\exp(-t)}{8m^2 t}-\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{8m^2 (t+1)^{\frac{1}{2}+m} t}\right)=\\=1-\ln(2)-\frac{\pi^2}{48}(\gamma+\ln(4))-\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{\pi^2 \exp(-t)}{48t}-\frac{6\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\frac{1}{t+1}}}{48\sqrt{t+1}\; t} \right)
$$
and finally

```
d0 = d01 + d02 // FullSimplify
N @ %
```

> ```
>  1/16 ( -4 Pi^2 (-1 + Log[2]) - 7 Zeta[3])
>  0.231229
> ```

$$d_0=d_{01}+d_{02}= \frac{4\pi^2\left(1-\ln(2)\right)- 7\zeta(3)}{16}$$

Comment: Thanks, But I need the value of $f'(0)$

Comment: I am sorry if I am not able to convey my question. I meant $f'(0)$ or the derivative of $f(a)$ at $0$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I need a closed form for the derivative of $f$ at $0$. Can we use "D" operator or any other idea can work?

Comment: Using Derivative[1][f][0] // TraditionalForm, can't we get a closed form of the derivative?

Comment: @Max This is just a closed form of the derivative $f'(0)$, however for unknown reasons it can't be numerically approximated.  Perhaps there is another symbolic representation of the result which could be numerically approximated.

Comment: I assume you meant in your previous comment "numerically evaluated," since you originally showed the derivative can be approximated. Complex-step differentiation also works: `Im[f[0 + 10.`32^-16 I]]/10^-16`. (+1, of course.)

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks.!  By closed form I meant the output of `Derivative[1][f][0]` which could not be evaluated with `N` unlike for e.g. `f'[-1]//N` or `f'[1]//N`. Several special functions have distinguished derivatives as other functions e.g. `MathieuSPrime` or `WeierstrassPPrime` similarily one could consider e.g. `Derivative[{0, 0, 1}, {0, 0}, 0][HypergeometricPFQ][{1/2, 1, 3/2}, {2, 2}, 1]` as a closed form.

Answer (score 3):

```
$Version

(* "13.2.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (January 27, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

f[a_] := HypergeometricPFQ[{1/2, (a + 1)/2, (a + 2)/2}, 
  {(a + 3)/2, (a + 3)/2}, 1]
```

This can be evaluated exactly for integers, a > -3

```
pts1 = {#, f[#]} & /@ Range[-2, 5] // Simplify

(* {{-2, 1}, {-1, 1}, {0, π^2/8}, {1, 4 - 8/π}, {2, 
  9/32 (-4 + π^2)}, {3, (64 (-7 + 3 π))/(27 π)}, {4, 
  75/512 (-16 + 3 π^2)}, {5, (64 (-149 + 60 π))/(375 π)}} *)
```

Or numerically for reals

```
SeedRandom[1234];

val = RandomReal[{-5, 5}, 10];

pts2 = {#, f[#]} & /@ val;

Plot[f[a], {a, -5, 5},
 Epilog -> {AbsolutePointSize[5],
   Red, Point[pts1],
   Purple, Point[pts2]}]
```

[image]

**EDIT:** For the derivative, `f'[a]`

```
Needs["NumericalCalculus`"]

ND[f[a], a, 0, WorkingPrecision -> 15] // N

(* 0.231229 *)

ListLinePlot[Table[{a0, ND[f[a], a, a0, WorkingPrecision -> 15]},
  {a0, 0, 5, 1/4}]]
```

[image]

Comment: +1 Thanks, but I need the value of $f'(0)$.

Comment: I am sorry if I am not able to convey my question. I meant $f'(0)$ or the derivative of $f(a)$ at $0$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I need a closed form for the derivative at $0$. Please see if it can be done.

Answer (score 2):

Mathematica evaluates a closed form as a ConditionalExpression

```
Limit[(f[a] - f[0])/a, a -> 0]
```

[image]

which is probably not useful because it contains unevaluated expressions of `HypergeometricPFQ` !

Comment: +1 Can we have a closed form of the limit you have written?

Comment: Yes, just evaluate the code!

Comment: @UlrichNeumann  It might be a version dependent issue,  in  *13.0.1*  it yields a `ConditionalExpression` which can't be evaluated numerically. If it is not the case in a newer version you should write down the result.

Comment: Yes please write down the result.